# Big Associative Array into Smaller Associative Arrays using Array_filter

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working on calculating the pass ratings of various football players. I have a .txt file that I'm pulling the info from.

```
while($line = fgetcsv($fp, 255, ',')){
$rate = round(calcPR($line),2);
$rating[$line[0]] = $rate;
} return $rating;
```

That was the portion of my function where I'm using a $fp to read from my .txt file and here is where I'm trying to display the data, but before I attempt to display my data I try to split the data into pass ratings that are great,good,mediocre, and poor.

For a great rating, they need to be above 95 so I have:

```
$grtRating = array_filter($rating,function(){
       return $rating > 95;
});
```

The rest of my code for good, mediocre, and poor looks just about the same, but with different criteria. How can I get this $grtRating array to store only the scores that are above 95?

Currently when I run my program it basically ignores the operators and displays all of the ratings no matter how low.

UPDATE:
Output of $poorRating array: (This is everything < 86)

```
Array ( [Cody Kessler] => 85.91 [Kirk Cousins] => 82.34 [Jacoby   Brissett] => 81.68 [Ryan Tannehill] => 81.2 [Tyrod Taylor] => 79.29 [Ben   Roethlisberger] => 77.49 [Shaun Hill] => 77.32 [Carson Palmer] => 74.79 [Jameis   Winston] => 73.93 [Marcus Mariota] => 73.06 [Joe Flacco] => 71.77 [Cam Newton]  => 70.32 [Josh McCown] => 70.25 [Trevone Boykin] => 69.2 [Jay Cutler] => 68.46  [Blake Bortles] => 67.13 [Brock Osweiler] => 66.1 [Blaine Gabbert] => 63.35  [Case Keenum] => 60.63 [Ryan Fitzpatrick] => 48.93 [Robert Griffin III] => 48.54  [Drew Stanton] => 34.36 [Kellen Clemens] => 2.07 )
```

I think the problem might be in how I output my code then. I have my links in an unordered list.

Here is an example:

```
<a href='pr.php?action=all'>All Ratings</a>
```

I have a `pr.php?action=great',`pr.php?action=good', `pr.php?action=mediocre', and`pr.php?action='poor'.

Here is how I output everything, is the problem how I do that?

```
$mode = 'all';

if ($_GET['action'] == 'great') $mode = 'great';
if ($_GET['action'] == 'good') $mode = 'good';
if ($_GET['action'] == 'mediocre') $mode = 'mediocre';
if ($_GET['action'] == 'poor') $mode = 'poor';

    if($mode == 'great'){
                    foreach($greatRating as $name=>$pr){
                            echo "<tr><td>{$name}</td><td>{$pr}</td></tr>\n";
                    }
            }
           if($mode == 'good'){
                    foreach($goodRating as $name=>$pr){
                    echo "<tr><td>{$name}</td><td>{$pr}</td></tr>\n";
                    }
             }
           if($mode == 'mediocre'){
                    foreach($mediocreRating as $name=>$pr){
                    echo "<tr><td>{$name}</td><td>{$pr}</td></tr>\n";
                    }
            }
           if($mode == 'poor'){
                    foreach($poorRating as $name=>$pr){
                    echo "<tr><td>{$name}</td><td>{$pr}</td></tr>\n";
                    }
            }
            if($mode = 'all'){
                    foreach($rating as $name=>$pr){
                    echo "<tr><td>{$name}</td><td>{$pr}</td></tr>\n";
                    }
            }


    echo "</table></div>\n";
}
```

Would you please help me figure out where my error is?

Comment: Your `$greatRating` should be `$grtRating`

Comment: I switched it to `$grtRating` now and it still doesn't work. EDIT: Just kidding, that totally was it, I feel like an idiot. I'll mark your answer as correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
$grtRating = array_filter($rating,function(){
    return $rating > 95;
});
```

with

```
$grtRating = array_filter($rating, function($val) {
   return $val > 95;
});
```

In the first one, you did not include the callback argument that contains the value passed from each iteration of the array, which will be the one used in your evaluation.

Comment: This still outputs every value for me. Is there something I did wrong maybe in my data output loops? Does this make a difference that I associated the name with the rating. So is it checking the names against the numbers by chance?

Comment: Can you try `print_r($rating)` and show me the output?

Comment: The output is: `Array ( [EJ Manuel] => 127.07 [Jimmy Garoppolo]=> 119.02 [Matt Ryan]=> 117.36)` There are a lot more values but I only listed a couple.

Comment: Can you `print_r($grtRating)` as well after filtering it? You can include your Array output in your question details.

Comment: Alright I'll post it there. I just checked and it is correctly outputted.